# What is this notation used for?

Tags: symbols

I am wondering what this notation `$\S$`  stands for and what is it used for? It looks like two S overlapping each other.

Comment: TRhe `\S` macro doesn't require math mode. It's sometimes (regularly?) called "paragraph", and it is used to denote various sectioning units of documents, especially legal documents.

Comment: Alright thank you, can it be used to refer to theorems or just specifically for paragraphs? @Mico

Comment: I'm not a mathematician or otherwise an authority on math nomenclature. I'll therefore let others take a shot at addressing your follow-up question.

Comment: Alright thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

Comment: @Mico I believe `\P` symbol is called "paragraph" and `\S` symbol is called "section". The `\S` symbol is popular as a section marker in legal documents, as you note, but also as a user icon on this site (go figure!!), https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes?tab=profile

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -Thanks.  From the wikipedia entry: "While § is usually read in spoken English as the word section, many other languages use the word 'paragraph' exclusively." I guess there's quite some terminological diversity here...

Comment: you can use any character for anything but I think it would be unusual/confusing to prefix throrems with it: it is normally used for sections with run-in headings (which may be thought of as titled paragraphs, hence the terminology differences) the question is also off topic here really since it's about the character not how to use it in tex.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (potentially) off-topic?! Not 100 % sure.